# Where should I start from in learning asp.net?

Tags: language-agnostic

Is it better to learn C# first and then ASP.NET or the reverse?

Best,

Gomanh

Answer (score 2):

Hi first of all you need to learn some C# basics, because ASP.NET uses C# or VB.NET syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand some fundamentals :)

ASP.NET is not a programming language. Its a "framework", meaning its a collection of libraries and classes related to web development. You access the ASP.NET frameworks through a programming language, such as C#.

If you're new to C#, there's a good chance you're new to .NET as well. The .NET Framework (also called the .NET Base Class Library) is a collection of classes which wrap up common needs that arise in most applications. C# language is actually very easy, but learning the .NET framework can be pretty challenging.

ASP.NET is a framework that uses the .NET BCL. Its *yet one more thing to learn*.

In my opinion, you can learn C# and ASP.NET simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are already familiar with HTML, otherwise lead with that.

ASP.Net is a framework that uses C#/VB to generate HTML, so you'd get lost pretty fast without an understanding of HTML. You can't really get far in ASP.Net without learning either C# or VB, as Juliet says, so the two would tend to happen side by side.

I learnt from an earlier edition of this book - [http://www.amazon.com/Sams-Teach-Yourself-ASP-NET-Hours/dp/0672333058/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1290212202&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672333058) otherwise highly recommend you spend some time on http://asp.net where they have excellent video resources for all levels.